# Getting invalid key format exception when loading a private key from .pem file

Tags: java, security, pem

I am trying to load a private key from a pem file. I am limited as I am not allowed to use any external library such as Bouncy Castle.

My piece of code:

```
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    File privKeyFile = new File(privateKeyPath);
    byte[] privKeyBytes = new byte[(int)privKeyFile.length()];
    KeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privKeyBytes);
    PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(ks);
```

Got exception in the last line. I also tried to convert the pem file to PKCS#8 using openssl:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -output DER -in mycert.pem -nocrypt > mynewcert.pk8
```

but I still get a "Invalid Key Format" exception

I thought that it might be a problem with my pem file, however after generating a new file using openssl:

```
openssl req -config "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\openssl.conf" -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem
```

I still get the same result.

Here is my pem file's content:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Here is my stacktrace:

```
    java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
    at Crypto.loadKeyPair(Crypto.java:165)
    at Crypto.signXML(Crypto.java:202)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.newKey(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

After some search around I couldn't find any further information. Now I am stuck and don't know what to do next. Please shed some lights, I really need some helps. Thanks!

Comment: post the exception stacktrace pls

Comment: have you tried splitting it into two files?(that is the key in one file and the certificate in another)

Comment: Stacktrace added. I already try spliting, by deleting the certificate part, but it still not works.

Comment: Note that the given pem file content (which you *should* split) still shows a PKCS#1 encoded private key, not a PKCS#8 encoded private key.

Comment: How do I know why I should split the file? Also how can I distinguish between those two formats? @owlstead could you please provide me some references?

Answer (score 0):

```java
KeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privKeyBytes);
PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(ks);
```

If you want to use above, then your private key file should be type of PKCS#8. but your file content is PKCS#1. so, use bountyCastle library or other way.

ps. Below content notice that your private key file is type of PKCS#1

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

PKCS#8 looks like

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```