# How can I create a Java KeyStore from an existing set of certificates and keys without using command line tools?

Tags: java, security, ssl

I obtain a randomly generated RSA certificate and private key as strings from another service, and I would like to use those strings to create a Java KeyStore.  All of the examples I see involve saving these strings to files, using the openssl and keytool command line tools to create the keystore on disk, and then loading the resulting KeyStore into memory (like [here](http://blog.softteco.com/2010/05/create-java-keystore-file-from-existing.html)).  However, it makes more sense for my purposes to create the KeyStore entirely in memory.

To that end, I am trying to use the Java Security API.  I am able to convert the certificate string into an instance of the `java.security.cert.Certificate` class, but I am unable to convert the private key into an instance of `java.security.PrivateKey`.  Here's method I am trying to create:

```java
private PrivateKey generatePrivateKey (String newKey) 
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
    InvalidKeySpecException, IOException {

//Configuring the KeyFactory to use RSA
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

//Convert the key string to a byte array
byte[] keyBytes = newKey.getBytes();

KeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);

PrivateKey key = kf.generatePrivate(ks);
return key;
}
```

Where the value of `newKey` is something like `"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEow...gNK3x\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"`.

When I run the code, I receive the following exception:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:217)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:372)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:341)
at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:367)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:91)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.newKey(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:75)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:316)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:213)
... 32 more
```

This particular error is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238179/getting-invalid-key-format-exception-when-loading-a-private-key-from-pem-file) stackoverflow question, and I would be grateful if that question were resolved, but I also want to know if my higher level goal (creating a JKS programmatically and solely in memory using Java) is feasible, and if so, whether I am on the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to decode base64 if your key is in the base64 representation:

```
KeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(newKey));
```

you can use org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 to do this.

if you want to generate keyPair you can you this code:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();

// extract the encoded private key, this is an unencrypted PKCS#8 private key
byte[] encodedprivkey = keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();
System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64String(encodedprivkey));
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I was trying to use the `Base64.decode(String)` method from JBoss Resteasy library, and I still got the `invalid format` error.  There was still two more things I needed to do though: 1) I needed to [trim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216969/getting-rsa-private-key-from-pem-base64-encoded-private-key-file) the first and last lines, and 2) I had to add the [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) Provider.  See the answer by Dimitris in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559272/algid-parse-error-not-a-sequence?rq=1) SO question.

Comment: yes, of course you need to trim the first and last line, since its not part of the key:) the second problem is probably that your key is not PKCS#8, do you really need to use a given key or can you generate your own key? if you can generate your own key, you can use key-generate-methods in my answer, it will creatre a PKCS#8 key, that you can use after it without problems